# Hovering over an Operator in Execution Plans: How to make the tooltip not disappear when moving the mouse

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, execution-plan

I want to share my screen and show an execution plan but when I hover my mouse over an operator and what to point to something with my mouse in the tooltip then it disappears. Is there a way to make a stay open while I point the mouse on some info on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Depending on the context, it might make more sense for you to use the Properties tab than the tool tip.

If you hit `f4`, or right click and choose Properties, you should see equivalent information (and more) show up in a pane on the right side of the screen.

[image: NUTS]

This may not meet all of your immediate needs, and there may be cases where you need to expand several other nodes within the Properties tab, but it should cover most scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Use the new "[Snip & Sketch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/snip-sketch/9mz95kl8mr0l)" and take a time-delayed snip:

[image]

Or hit the [Print Screen] button and paste the screen into Paint and snip it there.

Answer (score 3):

The time that a hint window is shown (it's [`TTDT_AUTOPOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ttm-setdelaytime) time), is based on your double-click time.

> The default delay times are based on the double-click time. For the default double-click time of 500 ms, the initial, autopop, and reshow delay times are 500ms, 5000ms, and 100ms respectively. The following code fragment uses the **[GetDoubleClickTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime)** function to determine the three delay times for any system.

To get hints to show for longer, increase the double-click time.

Before Windows 8, the value was configurable in the Control Panel.